# Pandas creating a consolidate report from excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file with below detail. I am trying to use panda to get only first 5 language and their sum in a excel

```
files   language    blank   comment code
61         Java     1031     533    3959
10         Maven    73        66    1213
12         JSON      0         0    800
32         XML       16       74    421
7          HTML      14       16    161
1      Markdown     23        0      39
1           CSS      0        0      1
```

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.read_csv("myfile_cloc.csv", nrows=20)
#df =  df.iloc[1:]
top_five = df.head(5)

print(top_five)
print(top_five['language'])
print(top_five['code'].sum())

d = {'Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)': "", 'LOC (CLOC)Only Code': 0}
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

newdf['Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)'] = str(top_five['language'])
newdf['LOC (CLOC)Only Code'] = top_five['code'].sum()

#Load excel to append the consolidated info
writer = newdf.ExcelWriter("myfile_cloc.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
book = load_workbook('myfile_cloc.xlsx')

writer.book = book
newdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='top_five', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Need suggestion in these line

```
newdf['Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)'] = str(top_five['language'])
newdf['LOC (CLOC)Only Code'] = top_five['code'].sum()
```

so that Expected Output can be

```
Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)  LOC (CLOC)Only Code
Java,Maven,JSON,XML,HTML          6554
```

Presently getting error

> ```
> raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

one way to solve this use  `index` attribute

```
a=df.head()
df=pd.DataFrame({"Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)": ','.join(a['language'].unique()),"LOC (CLOC)Only Code":a['code'].sum()},index=range(1))
```

another way to solve this,
use `from_records` and pass list of dict in Dataframe.

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records([{"Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)": ','.join(a['language'].unique()),"LOC (CLOC)Only Code":a['code'].sum()}])
```

Output:

```
    Languages (CLOC) (Top 5 Only)    LOC (CLOC)Only Code
0        Java,Maven,JSON,XML,HTML                   6554
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd
sheet1 = pd.read_csv("/home/mycomputer/Desktop/practise/sorting_practise.csv")
sheet1.head()
sortby_blank=sheet1.sort_values('blank',ascending=False)
sortby_blank['blank'].head(5).sum()
values = sortby_blank['blank'].head(5).sum()
```

/home/nptel/Desktop/practise/sorting_practise.csv ---> File Directory

blank ---> Column you want to sort

use .tail() if you need bottom values

"values" variable will have the answer you are looking for

Comment: This is not an expected answer

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Yeah missed sum, check it now it should be working

Comment: Actually he has done all the sum ops. He gets stuck while creating this scalar values into dataframe. If you add details regarding the issue it would be appreciable :)

Comment: @MohamedThasinah check it now. Variable "Values"